# Android: How to register for intent iff another condition is met

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have two apps on the play store . Both of them handle an intent and run a service based on it.

However I do not want them to compete and if both are installed I only want App A to show in the Android App chooser and not App B.

How would I keep App B from trying to handle the intent if App A is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Android handles intents internally so when you say an activity is registered for handling an intent it will most likely be via Action field.

If you want two activities to have the same action and to suppress one Activity from showing in Chooser, then it is not possible unless you modify the Android OS.

> However I do not want them to compete and if both are installed I only want App A to show in the Android App chooser and not App B

Activities do not "compete" for starting up, its usually the user who chooses which activity to start when an action is specified. So if you want AppA to only show in the chooser, you can declare a different action for AppB.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I say "compete" I literally meant that I don't want App B to take traffic away from App A.

Comment: So to understand: If I have two apps that both have a service declared in their Android Manifest to Handle 
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="something"/>
 </intent-filter>
It is not possible to bypass the App chooser for App B if App A is installed.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html reading through this it seems that this is the case.